# SurfaceView displays the noise at the camera image

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I have some troubles with displaying camera viewfinder on Galaxy S2 (android 2.3) and LG P500 (android 2.3). I have some noise (interference) on SurfaceView. Nevertheless, result photo hasn't such defects.

[image: View of the issue]

Other devices (include devices with 2.3 and Galaxy S2 with android 4) working fine.

Unfortunatly, I haven't such devices, so I can't test it after every changing in source code. Maybe someone already had this problem?

Also, I tried to test this app using Samsung Remote Test Lab, but, unfortunatly, Galaxy S2 with android 2.3 was placed on the table and his camera takes blackness (splash do nothing). In this case there are no any white strips.

**onCreate()**:

```
mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
...
mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**onResume()**:

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
if (mCamera == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.t_no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
} else {
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

    p.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    prepareFlash();
    if (prepareResolution()) {
        Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(mDisplay.getWidth(), mDisplay.getHeight(), p);
        if (size != null) {
            p.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
        }
    }

    mCamera.setParameters(p);

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

**surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder):**

```
try {
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any idea? What could it be? I will be grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start camera preview in Portrait mode; bugs with such preview occur on different devices. Sometimes, these bugs get fixed with software upgrade from the manufacturer, sometimes, they are not. Sometimes, crazy workarounds can resolve the problem.

To be on the safe side, stick with Landscape mode. Maybe your app can keep a black list of devices/build versions where the preview activity will not allow vertical (portrait) orientation.

Note that you can usually *simulate* portrait orientation by using rotated icons, bitmaps, and even text labels.

Comment: The problem can be solved in two ways: change activity orientation to landscape or remove setPreviewSize from the code. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: If `setPreviewSize()` may cause problems,  then probably `getBestPreviewSize()` logic is wrong. Note that you only need to mess with `setPreviewSize()` if you use `setPreviewCallback()`.